# Excel 2003: Better workaround for 10 if statements

Tags: excel, if-statement

[image]I have a very rough workaround for 10 statements using a combination of 2 cells, as follows

```
Cell 1 (O2)
=IF(C2="TW2-OUT",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,8,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,9,FALSE),IF(C2="TW2-IN",IF($D2="","",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE)),IF(C2="Playing",IF($D2="","",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,8,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,9,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE)),IF(C2="IN1OUT2",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,9,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE),IF(C2="TW1-OUT",IF($D2="","",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,8,FALSE)),IF(C2="TW1-IN",IF($D2="","",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,9,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE)),IF(C2="TW3-OUT",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,8,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,9,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE),0)))))))+P2

Cell 2 (P2)
 =IF(C2="TW3-IN",IF($D2="","",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,11,FALSE)),IF(C2="IN2OUT3",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE),IF(C2="IN1OUT3",VLOOKUP($D2,Players,9,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($D2,Players,10,FALSE),0)))
```

Is there a better way of doing this.  I have read via a Google search about using a table approach with an array to achieve the same effect.  However, in my case the status of a player determines the score of a player and this complicates things for me.  Here are the 10 possible statuses (if statements) broken down as follows with how scored are calculated:

```
TransferStatuses    Cols
Playing             8+9+10+11
TW1-IN              9+10
TW1-OUT             8
TW2-IN              10+11
TW2-OUT             8+9
TW3-IN              11
TW3-OUT             8+9+10
IN1OUT2             9
IN1OUT3             9+10
IN2OUT3             10



8 = ColK (Transfer Window 0)
9 = ColL(Transfer Window 1)
10 = ColM (Transfer Window 2)
11 = ColN(Transfer Window 3)
```

The 'score' array will be along the lines as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$S$2:$T$11,2,FALSE)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to put it all together to make it work, i.e. I have to extend my formula to 300 cells but I don't know how to implement it so that the array calculates the scores correctly for each player?

Can someone help?

Comment: If you can post a spreadsheet or even a screenshot, it may help clarify things.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea.  It is very hard to write this up.  I will upload a sample in a few mins....just have to work out how to do it

Comment: Image uploaded, but could not work out how to upload a sample file, which I had created.  Hopefully, the screenshot is good enough, if not let me know I will upload to a file sharing site, etc.  BTW, thanks for looking and for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I would approach it like this:

Set up a matrix of binary values that specify, for each status, which columns should be added up. Use `OFFSET` and `MATCH` to look up the status for each data row and return the array/range of binary values, and `SUMPRODUCT` to sum it all up. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: +1....but could I suggest an "improvement"? Non-volatile INDEX is normally preferable to volatile OFFSET, i.e. =SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(B$4:E$13,MATCH(A19,A$4:A$13,0),0),B$19:E$19)

Comment: +1 for that very real improvement. I started writing INDEX but for some reason I didn't think it could return an array.

Comment: Glad to know -- but please note @barryhoudini's substitution of INDEX is superior to my suggestion of OFFSET. The formula is exactly the same otherwise.

Comment: Barry:  Thanks for the improvement - not sure of the difference between non-volatile and volatile but I will Google for an answer.  I and delighted that both formulas work - I would never have worked that out and learnt something along the way

Comment: Volatile (OFFSET) means Excel will recalculate the formula if anything changes in the workbook. Non-volatile formulas like INDEX will only recalc if a predecessor value changes. It's not a big deal either way in a small workbook, but non-volatile formulas will be much more efficient in a large workbook. HTH

Comment: Wow!  Great write up - I know what you mean now.  Thanks again Andy